# OpenShift nameservers / public IP

Tags: nameserver, cloud-hosting, domain-forwarding

I have configured a website on openshift it is working fine with the openshift's generated url. But I am unable to find a valid publicIP or nameserver on which I will map the domain name. Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters. Unfortunately, as written, this is off-topic here.  There is insufficient information fir us to discern where you are having issues and also your question appears site specific. Maybe, with more detail it would be a fit on sister site superuser com.

Comment: Things that might help is advising your domain name and openshift URL.  Presumably the URL will include sufficient information to deduce an IP address - but you will also need to ensure Openshift recognises your domain as related  with the site - maybe something you need to reach out to them to solve.